# How to fix "Breaks and labels are different lengths" when using ggplot2 for faceted plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 70, 0.5),
                 y = seq(0, 70, 0.5),
                 val = rnorm(141),
                 group =rep(1:3,47))

max_val_plot <- df$val %>%  max() %>% round(0)
min_val_plot <--df$val %>%  min() %>% round(0)

breaks_plot <-seq(min_val_plot,max_val_plot,0.1) 

n <- breaks_plot %>%  length()

getPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"))

colors_plot <-getPalette(n)

labels_plot <- breaks_plot %>%
  as.character() 
labels_plot[!1:0]=' '

df %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=val))+
  geom_raster()+
  facet_grid(~group)+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)+
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    name = "",
    colours = colors_plot,
    breaks = breaks_plot,
    labels = labels_plot
  )
```

Although labels and breaks are of equal length, the error `"Breaks and labels are different lengths"`  is returned due to the presence of multiple groups and the faceted function in plotting code.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine. I don't get an error when I run your code with the provided example data.

Comment: run it a few times and you will get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to pass a function to the `labels` argument of `scale_fill_xxx` to create the labels on the fly instead of providing the labels as a vector.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = val)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_grid(~group) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    name = "",
    colours = colors_plot,
    breaks = breaks_plot,
    labels = function(x) { x <- as.character(x); x[!1:0] <- " "; x}
  )
```

[image]